# Is there a way to determine whether a representation of a finite group is faithful?

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory, characters

I want to determine whether a representation of a finite group is faithful from the character table.
Is there a such general way or specific way for finite group of small order?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand the answer you refered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your question has been settled here:

[Faithful representations and character tables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32648/faithful-representations-and-character-tables)

In short, a finite dimensional irreducible representation over $\mathbb{C}$, say  $\rho : G \to \operatorname{GL}(V)$, is faithful if and only if $\chi_\rho(g) = \dim V$ only when $g = 1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The answer is quite easy and simple.